# Nth entry of an m digit variable base number

Tags: combinatorics

Given an m digit integer where each of its digits is written in a different base, what is the nth ordered entry. E.g. imagine a 3 digit number, where the right most digit is in base 2, next digit in base 2 and the left most in base 2. then we can write all the combinations as just 000, 001, 002, 010, 011, 012, 100, 101, 102, 110, ...

so given n , what is nth entry for an m digit number where each digit can be in a different base?

Comment: Since your question contains variables, it's better to [typeset them in MathJax](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22029/290189).

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand correctly you want the numbers to be ordered and then get the $n$th biggest? Well this does not change actually if you have every digit in a different basis. If your basis is given by $b_i$, $i=1\cdot m$, i.e. $b_i$ is the basis of the $i$th digit, then the number $a_ma_{m-1}\ldots a_0$ is given by

$$\sum_{k=0}^m a_k \prod_{j=1}^kb_j$$

Note that by convention $\prod_{j=1}^0b_j = 1$. Let us see this in an example where we have a 3-digit number with the first digit in base 5, the second in base 2 and the third in base 3. Then the number 410 corresponds to

$$4 \cdot (2\cdot 3) + 1\cdot 3+ 0\cdot 1$$

Note that the 5 does not appear, it only appears in the sense that the 3rd digit can never be larger than 4.

The numbers are still ordered by first filling up the last digit digit, then the second to last and so forth until the 1st digit. In our case, it would be

000, 001, 002, 010, 011, 012, 100, 101, 102, 110, 111, 112, 200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 300, 301, 302, 310, 311, 312, 400, 401, 402, 410, 411, 412

I am explaining this since I feel like this may have been unclear.

Now to answer your actual question: if you want to get the $n$th number, simply take the number $n-1$ (in basis 10) and write it in your basis in the same way you would normally change between bases of numbers. The reason it is $n-1$ and not $n$ is that 0 is the first number, 1 the second and so forth.

In our case, the 4th number is the number 3 written in our (5,2,3) basis, i.e.

$$3 = 0\cdot (2\cdot 3) + 1\cdot 3 + 0\cdot 1 = 010$$

Let me know if this does not answer your question. Note also that I am counting my digits starting from the left, so the first digit of 123 to me is 1.